# Java generics and "Bound mismatch"

Tags: java, generics

I have a number some classes that user java generics and everything was working fine until I added some additional layers to the class hierarchy.

I am wondering if the problem is related to "type erasure" but I am not sure how to express the inheritance to eliminate this.

Class definitions:

```
public interface IBaseDAO <T, PK extends Serializable>;
public interface IEntityDAO<T extends BaseEntity> extends IBaseDAO<T, Integer>;
public interface IBaseFileDAO<T extends File> extends IEntityDAO<T>;
public interface IInvoiceDAO extends IBaseFileDAO<Invoice>;

public class BaseDAO<T, PK extends Serializable>  implements IBaseDAO<T, PK>;
public abstract class EntityDAO<T extends BaseEntity> extends BaseDAO<T, Integer> implements IEntityDAO<T>;
public abstract class BaseFileDAO<T extends File> extends EntityDAO<T> implements IBaseFileDAO<T>;
public class InvoiceDAO extends BaseFileDAO<Invoice> implements IInvoiceDAO;

public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable;
public class File extends BaseEntity;
public abstract class Transaction extends File;
public class Request extends Transaction;
public class Invoice extends Request;
```

The errors are:

```
Bound mismatch: The type Invoice is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends File> of the type BaseFileDAO<T>
Bound mismatch: The type Invoice is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends File> of the type IBaseFileDAO<T>
```

I am a bit out of my depth here, can anyone give me some advice on how to express the Invoice class to eliminate the error?

EDIT:

Not sure if this helps but I also have:

```
public class FileDAO extends BaseFileDAO<File> implements IFileDAO;
public interface IFileDAO extends IBaseFileDAO<File>;
```

Comment: I can't believe it requires 13 classes/interfaces to exhibit this problem.  Please can you construct a minimal example, so that it's easier to read.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a conflict with `java.io.File`?

Comment: should it be `IEntityDAO<T extends File>` and `EntityDAO<T extends File>`

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I am sorry I would have liked to have presented a simpler case. But I don't really understand what is causing the problem, so it is difficult for me to write code that reproduces it. I daresay that someone who knew what the cause was could.produce a simpler case.

Comment: @JimGarrison Jim I am pretty sure there are no conflicts with the Java.io class since it only since the addition of the InvoiceDAO, Transaction, Request and Invoice classes that I have had a problem at all.

Comment: @hairyone: Just start simplifying you hierarchy until the problem disappears...

Comment: @gigadot Yes EntityDAO<T extends BaseEntity> is correct in that File is not the only class extends BaseEntity.

Comment: When these are created as empty classes, the error does not occur (at least as inner classes, under Eclipse).  You didn't include the line number where the problem is occurring.  I suspect it's dependent on code inside the classes that we can't guess at.

Comment: @EdStaub  I have just checked the line numbers and they correspond with the class definition line "public class ...." and do not appear to related to the code within the classes.

Comment: Can you double check that Invoice is the class you expect - is it possible that you're importing a different Invoice into InvoiceDAO? Seems unlikely...

Comment: Do you get the errors if you try `Request` for `Invoice` in `IInvoiceDAO` and `InvoiceDAO`?

Comment: Apologies to all who tried to help me with this issue.

Whilst testing the code suggested by Tom Hawtin I created a separate project in Eclipse and after compiling it the errors in the problem project disappeared as well. It would appear that the project simply needed a "Refresh..". I think Eclipse must have at some point become confused by successive edits.

Comment: Voting to close... or delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've messed your question up... This compiles for me:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

interface IBaseDAO <T, PK extends Serializable> { }
interface IEntityDAO<T extends BaseEntity> extends IBaseDAO<T, Integer> { }
interface IBaseFileDAO<T extends File> extends IEntityDAO<T> { }
interface IInvoiceDAO extends IBaseFileDAO<Invoice> { }

class BaseDAO<T, PK extends Serializable>  implements IBaseDAO<T, PK> { }
abstract class EntityDAO<T extends BaseEntity> extends BaseDAO<T, Integer> implements IEntityDAO<T> { }
abstract class BaseFileDAO<T extends File> extends EntityDAO<T> implements IBaseFileDAO<T> { }
class InvoiceDAO extends BaseFileDAO<Invoice> implements IInvoiceDAO { }

abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable { }
class File extends BaseEntity { }
abstract class Transaction extends File { }
class Request extends Transaction { }
class Invoice extends Request { }
```

There is nothing to do with type erasure here [in code presented].

Comment: I just created a new project in Eclipse with the code you suggested and you are quite correct it compiles with just a few warnings about serialVersionUID!.